# How to convert grouped index to regular index dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by, fillna

## I would like to convert a grouped index dataframe as the one down there:

```
              stock branches_code
products_code                     
1017626            5       Branch 23
                   1       Branch  7
                   1       Branch 44
                   1       Branch 43
                   1       Branch 46
```

## To something like this:

```
              stock branches_code
products_code                     
1017626            5       Branch 23
1017626            1       Branch 7
1017626            1       Branch 44
1017626            1       Branch 43
1017626            1       Branch 46
```

***In Pandas 1.4.x***

*Any Ideas would be greatly appreciated!*

### Update:

The script that created the grouped dataframe is this one:

```
sum_df = df.groupby(['products_code', 'branches_code']).agg({"stock": "sum"})
```

Comment: Can you add the script that created the first dataframe to your question?

Comment: Updated the question to include the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use reset_index() for ungrouping your index and use set_index(column_name) for setting coulmn as index

```
sum_df = df.groupby(['products_code', 'branches_code']).agg({"stock": "sum"})
sum_df = sum_df.reset_index() # don't use drop=True
```

Above line will give simple dataframe with a new index (numbered from 0 to n)

Comment: What gave me the exact behavior I wanted was a close variation to your code where I used set_index('products_code') to get rid of the regular index. I also tried with fillna and it worked fine for me but your method seems simpler so I will mark it as the correct answer.

Thank you so much.